# How to use levels or curves to remove the less luminous and smallest points on an astronomy photography?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How can I retouch photos of supernova veils to remove the smallest stars of the picture?

The goal is to allow the viewer to focus on the [central nebula remains pattern](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:EasternveilBicolorHunterWilson.jpg), without too many stars artifacts.

Two examples are:

[image]

[image]

My first idea was to use Adobe Photoshop for `Blending Options > Blend` if... and adjust levels, but if I raise the lower luminosity threshold to discard of less luminous pixels, I discard too the aura of the luminous items.

I had no more chance with curves, but I have no real intuition or knowledge about how to efficiently use curves to achieve this result.

This question **isn't limited to a particular software**, if a software is more efficient for this task than Adobe Photoshop, the answer seems interesting too.

---

(*) Description: This Spitzer image transforms a dark cloud into a silky translucent veil, revealing the stellar winds from an otherwise hidden newborn star called HH46-IR. Spitzer's remarkable capacity to peer through cosmic dust allowed it to unveil this never-before-seen star.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you have a couple of options, personally I would play with the levels (Image > Adjustments >Levels) as there is plenty of control and I can't imagine you want to get rid of all of the stars but this certainly works for a tidy of the small and less luminous ones.

You can see a before/after below. I wan't sure how much of the starry noise that you wanted to get rid of so I just reduced it a little.

[image: before after]

In the next photo I adjusted the levels and also added a noise reduction filter (Filter > Noise > Reduce Noise.

So the filter;

[image: filter]

And before and after;

[image: Beforeafter segment]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed, to keep some start is better. Yes, that helps! Thank you.